# What is the difference between / and : on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, prefix

From what I understand, what I would call files and folders, are just objects on Amazon S3. They are all located in the same region specified, and all in one big sea of files. The prefix of those object (the first one) is what Amazon calls "bucket". So, an object could look like this "Bucket01:anotherprefix:athirdprefix:myfile"

But I've seen that some objects have / in them. anotherprefix:athirdprefix:afourthprefix/myfile

What does / do? Because I can't see that it behaves any other way than :

Answer (score 0):

The '/' does 'do' anything, it becomes part of the name. Lots of people use them, including me, because it visually organizes your files in a convention that most people are used to, but that is just a convention, as you have said, there are no folders or subdirectories within a bucket - just 'one big sea of files'.

Naming convention general is not going to matter, unless and until you have lots and lots of objects within a bucket, and need better performance - if you think that might be your case eventually, best to come up with a naming convention where the beginning of the file names are 'randomized' to some extent to allow s3 to distribute your files for you, and thus access them faster when it needs them.

Here is a slidehare that you might find interesting on best practices for naming conventions:

http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/maximizing-amazon-s3-performance-stg304-aws-reinvent-2013

Comment: So in my example, the "afourthprefix/myfile" is the name?

Comment: Right, the / is just part of the name. Could just as easily been an 'e' or and 'x' for example

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I guess some clients interpret it as a folder, once the object is downloaded. At least S3cmd does (s3tools)